# What is the ideal solution for a repository in my case?

Tags: c#, xna, repository

I am trying to implement something similar to *Scrabble* or [Letter Quest](http://www.letterquestgame.com/). I am still using XNA with C#. The game I write has to be able to check if the user input is a valid word in the dictionary. So I wonder what would be the most efficient way to implement a repository for the dictionary. I can think of two things:

1. I could save all the valid words in XML files.
2. I could make the user install and use a Service-based database (SQL)

I think XML files have the disadvantage of having a poor lookup performance compared to SQL, note this is just an assumption of my own I do not know this for sure. On the other hand SQL might produce a little overhead during installation of the game if the user has no *SQL Server Express* installed, he will be forced to download it. Well actually the download will start automatically, still it requires a internet connection.

So what would be a good solution for this? Is there maybe another way I have not thought of? I am open to any suggestion. Also if you think that I got something wrong in my thoughts above, please let me know.

Comment: Well, assuming there are *alot* of words, it is probably smarter to use a database. And on the other hand, why would you not let them install SQL Server Express?

Comment: Because when using sql I have the feeling of forcing something upon the user. I do not want to create frustration. I also thought it would be best to avoid any additional dependencies. Just imagine there might be people out there who desperately want to play my game but have no internet connection :D

Comment: As @DionV. said, the better solution would be to use a database. But there are good solutions that do not require the installation of an SQL Server. You can use database solutions that are file based or look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org).

Comment: Well, you could save all valid words in an XML file and load it at startup. You can then save them in a `HashSet` for an O(1) lookup. Only thing is that it will probably consume a fair amount of memory.

Comment: @DionV. Let's assume german has around 5 million words, lets say in average 10 letters, that would be ~50 mb of data. I do not have to worry about 50MB memory nowadays, do I?

Comment: [English has over 1 billion already](http://www.languagemonitor.com/number-of-words/number-of-words-in-the-english-language-1008879/). It would be better if you'd not have to worry about the internet connection.